# Vector scaling in python

Tags: python, mathematics, vector

[image]

I believe it's an easy math function, but I don't have any idea how to solve it.
I have a 2D vector that I want to multiply to a certain length. But I only have the x value of this new location so how do I get the y component of the new location?
In other words, I have the vector start and end positions, I also have the new end x value, how to get the y value?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just scaling the length it should just be a "similar triangles" problem. If you have the start and end points, then you can subtract them to get the original x and y vectors. Then if you have the new x, it's all proportional.

x / y = x2 / y2

So rearranging the equation should be

y2 = (x2 * y) / x

Comment: Thank you Dale, it's working on paper, I'll implement it soon.